# How to import Sectigo code signing certificate into Windows certificate store

Tags: certificate, code-signing

We have a C# .net application that we want to code sign. I've purchased a certificate through Sectigo and have a PEM file and the Certificate Signing Request (that was generated on the web page by Sectigo when I applied for the certificate).

I can't load the PEM file into the Windows Certificate store, it appears it needs to be in p12 format. It appears I can use OpenSSL to convert this, however when I run the command below:

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in newcert.pem -out newcert.p12`

I get the error:

`Could not read private key from -in file from newcert.pem`

I have the Certificate Signing Request, but not a private key. Can I use the CSR as the private key? The Sectigo documentation on this is lacking.

Comment: The CSR contains only the public key. If you've lost the private key the certificate is useless. You can ask your CA to issue a new one, using a new key pair.